# Windows Subsystem for Linux without Windows Store

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to set up the Bash on Ubuntu prompt on my new Windows laptop.  I've enabled developer mode and the `Windows Subsystem for Linux` is enabled, but I don't see a Bash on Ubuntu prompt.  According to [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) the next step is to install a Linux distribution, but I know I was able to do this a few months ago on my old laptop without the Windows store, which was also running 1703.

Comment: Please update your question to include which build of Windows 10 you are using.  As for you being able to install WSL a few months ago without the Windows Store, you were likely not using 1709 a few months ago, Windows Subsystem for Linux, was still a beta feature in 1703.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is this:

```
open menu --> execute --> cmd --> bash
```

Then the ubuntu cli will start.